# How to show other database information with onmouseover?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, json

Updated.2
I've got a MySQL database and am able to retrieve information and have json encode.

```
<?php
$mysqli_db_hostname = "localhost";
$mysqli_db_user = "root";
$mysqli_db_password = "password";
$mysqli_db_database = "database";



$con = @mysqli_connect($mysqli_db_hostname, $mysqli_db_user, $mysqli_db_password,
 $mysqli_db_database);

if (!$con) {
 trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$var = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM uploads";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
$var[] = $obj;
}
echo '{"uploads":'.json_encode($var).'}';

?>
```

You can see that height, brand and model are in a single row on my html page below.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>  
$('#jsondata tr').mouseover(function(){
  var row = $(this).prop('id');
  $('#jsondata'+row).show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
  var row = $(this).prop('id');
  $('#jsondata'+row).hide();
 });
</script>

<table class="mGrid" id="jsondata">
<thead>
<th>height</th>
<th>brand</th>
<th>model</th>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
<div id="result">
<table class="mGrid" id="specific1">
<thead>
<th>email</th>
<th>height</th>
<th>location</th>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var url="data_retrieval.php";
 $("#jsondata tbody").html("");
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
$.each(data.uploads, function(i,user){
var newRow =
"<tr>"
+"<td>"+user.height+"</td>"
+"<td>"+user.brand+"</td>"
+"<td>"+user.model+"</td>"
+"</tr>" ;
$(newRow).appendTo("#jsondata tbody");
 });
    $.each(data.uploads, function(i,user){
        var newdiv =
        '<table id="specific'+i+'"><tr><td>'+user.email+'</td><td>'+user.height+'</td><td>'+user.location+'</td></tr></table>';
        $(newdiv).appendTo("#result"); // Should be an DIV....
});
});
});
</script>
```

I'd like to retrieve the height, brand and model without obstructing the retrieval of the new info too. Anyone know how to go about this? Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**//EDIT2:** Just try the code above so my script should do the rest! (comments)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url="data_retrieval.php";
    $("#jsondata tbody").html("");
    $.getJSON(url,function(data){
        $.each(data.uploads, function(i,user){
            var newRow =
            "<tr>"
            +"<td>"+user.height+"</td>"
            +"<td>"+user.brand+"</td>"
            +"<td>"+user.model+"</td>"
            +"</tr>" ;
            $(newRow).appendTo("#jsondata tbody");
        });
        $.each(data.uploads, function(i,user){
            var newdiv =
            '<table id="specific'+i+'"><tr><td>'+user.DATASPECIFIC+'</td><td>'+user.DATASPECIFIC2+'</td><td>'+user.DATASPECIFIC3+'</td></tr></table>';
            $(newdiv).appendTo("#jsondataspecific"); // Should be an DIV....
        });
    });
});
```

**//EDIT:** Added `.mouseleave()` to hide it....

```js
  $('#jsondata tr').mouseover(function(){
   var row = $(this).prop('id');
   $('#specific'+row).show();
  }).mouseleave(function(){
   var row = $(this).prop('id');
   $('#specific'+row).hide();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mGrid" id="jsondata">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>height</th><th>brand</th><th>model</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr id="1">
<td>5 feet</td><td>newbrand</td><td>55-v2</td>
</tr>
<tr id="2">
<td>15 feet</td><td>newbrand2</td><td>55-v3</td>
</tr>
<tr id="3">
<td>51 feet</td><td>newbrand3</td><td>65-v5</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<table class="mGrid" id="specific1" style="display: none; background-color: green;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>other info1</th><th>other info1</th><th>other info1</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>This is specific1</td><td>This is specific1</td><td>This is specific1</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="mGrid" id="specific2" style="display: none; background-color: red;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>other info2</th><th>other info2</th><th>other info2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>This is specific2</td><td>This is specific2</td><td>This is specific2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="mGrid" id="specific3" style="display: none; background-color: yellow;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>other info3</th><th>other info3</th><th>other info3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>This is specific3</td><td>This is specific3</td><td>This is specific3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Greetings from Vienna

Comment: Just quick info, the rows don't disappear once the mouse leaves the corresponding row.

Comment: Bernd, hey thanks for commenting. Unfortunately, the code doesn't seem to be working with my jquery that parses the json data. I'm looking for something that basically uses a mouseover function on the retrieved json data, in my case it's height, brand and model. And when moused over it should show more data from the same source (data_retrieval.php). I hope that makes sense.

Comment: So data_retrieval returns more than "height, brand and model" and you want to display first this 3 types and on mouseover you want to show the other informations?

Comment: Exactly! Data_retrieval.php returns the whole table.

Comment: still got nothing. I updated what my page looks like. Perhaps I input some stuff wrong?

Comment: You have to make an new `div $(newdiv).appendTo("#jsondataspecific"); // Should be an DIV....` called **jsondataspecific** and in this div should the over rest be loaded

Comment: but it shouldn't matter what it's called, right? Instead of #jsondataspecific I have #result because that's the name of the new div.

Comment: Yes. So look on the source code (post it) and the script?

Comment: sorry, i don't understand your question.

Comment: i had posted your script in mine yesterday. I updated it and you can view it in my original question.

Comment: Your 2 functions: mouseover, mouseleave should be `$('#specific'+row)` .show()/.hide()....

Comment: ya i tried that the first time, didn't work, so then I messed around with it. It seems I am doomed to wander through the dark forest of programming mediocrity forever! (There's a bit of sarcasm in that last sentence.) I had a friend mention angular js. Maybe that could help things??